# php mysql execute 2 insert statements based on first insert ID

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I am able to do:

When a user fills out a form to sign up the script will insert sign up info into table **ps_reg_users**. This table contains basic profile information.

I have added a Badge/Achievement section to display badges based on certain criteria.

What I need to do:

Once the user signs up, add that user to another table **ps_badges** with the **id** from the first query.

The **id** is set to auto increment on table **ps_reg_users** and inserts **NULL** upon submit, thus assigning the next **id**.

How would I INSERT a query to **ps_reg_users** then retrieve the **id** after it creates it to make another query based on that **id**?

***PHP***

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "reg_users` ( `id` , `first_name` , `last_name` , `password` , `email` , `date_time` , `user_status`, `verify_code` , `reward_points`, `ref_user`)
                    VALUES (NULL , '$first_name', '$last_name', '$password', '$e_email', '$date_time' , 'y', '$verify_code', '0' , '$ref_uid')";
```

This ^ works.

***I need to execute this right after***

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "badges` ( `user_id` , `pts_reputation` , `pts_comments` , `pts_uploads` , `pts_downloads` , `pts_featured` , `pts_activity`, `pts_refer`, `pts_donator` , `pts_country`)
            VALUES (NULL , '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', NULL)";
```

I hope im not over explaining, I think I need to tap into LAST_INSERT_ID() but how would I get it from the first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic sequence:

```
$sql = "INSERT ....";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$id = mysql_insert_id();

$sql = "INSERT .... (id,...) VALUES ($id, ...);"
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Of course, you're still using an obsolete interface and SHOULD be switching to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Thank you, yes I realize I need to be using mysqli, @ this point the script wont be updated anymore.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_insert_id(); mysql function returns last inserted id